# Better word than 'vindictive' to describe feeling a desire to destroy or break something

Tags: single-word-requests

The [*Oxford Dictionary of Difficult Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA460&lpg=PA460&dq=%22having+or+showing+a+strong+or+unreasoning+desire+for+revenge%22&source=bl&ots=d1TZnLc5MN&sig=vkc8H4GnyYUu6jOnNm6-rE31ZMc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwA2oVChMIw_Pe7pzzxgIV0VmICh1T1gXb#v=onepage&q=%22having%20or%20showing%20a%20strong%20or%20unreasoning%20desire%20for%20revenge%22&f=false) defines *vindictive* as follows:

> having or showing a strong or unreasoning desire for revenge.

What is a word for a having desire to be destructive or to break something?

Comment: 'vindictive' is an adjective, 'desire' is a noun. Which are you asking for?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: You should change "deatoy" to "destroy".

Comment: I added a link to the definition you quoted, but doing this yourself is a good habit to get in when you post questions or answers on EL&U. Also, please note that citing "Google" as a source is essentially meaningless, since Google is not the actual source of the quotation (an Oxford dictionary is).

Comment: Sorry, I was on my mobile, and my wife wasn't happy I was spending so much time on it.  I would have done a better job formatting and referencing otherwise.  Thank you for the edit though!

Comment: How about "resentful"?

Comment: I was hoping for a word that doesn't apply those feelings towards one thing or person, but just a general desire for any/all things.

Comment: @rogermue, I've noticed that in some other SE sites, one is encouraged to edit the question when one notices a typo or formatting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To emphasize the unreasoning nature of the destructive tendencies, I would suggest the following:

**wantonly** *destructive*

The Merriam-Webster dictionary defines wanton as:

> Full Definition of WANTON
>
> 1. (a) archaic :  hard to control :  undisciplined, unruly; (b) :  playfully mean or cruel :  mischievous
> 2. (a) :  lewd, bawdy; (b) :  causing sexual excitement :  lustful, sensual
> 3. (a) :  merciless, inhumane ; (b) :  having no just foundation or provocation :  malicious
> 4. :  being without check or limitation: as (a) :  luxuriantly rank ; (b) :  unduly lavish :  extravagant 
>      — wan·ton·ly adverb

It will be obvious from the context that the second meaning is not intended.

Comment: I think malicious is the best word for what I was looking for.  Thanks!  :)
(I'll give you an accepted, even though it was listed as a synonym.)

Answer (score 1):

Enraged, explosive, ferocious, fierce, savage, fiery, feisty, furious, raging, uncontrollable, volatile, violent, wild.  This gives you some options to choose from.

Comment: I like volatile, but I think malicious (see Marconius's answer) was the word I wanted, but a +1 for the direction.  Thanks. :)

Comment: @JacobHolloway - that's interesting.  I have a child who has Tourette Syndrome and ADHD, and sometimes does damage through rage or impulsivity.  But I tend to make a distinction when reassuring people, by saying he can be volatile, but he's not malicious.  In other words, he doesn't purposely try to cause any damage -- and yet he bumps into people through carelessness, and throws his glasses against the wall in a rage occasionally. ...  Now I'm curious how you are going to use *malicious*.